# WP Rest API returns 500 internal server error

Tags: wordpress, api, endpoint, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WP Rest API v2 plugin.
I'm calling this api endpoint with POST method.

`https://example.site/wp-json/wp/v2/custom_posttype/111111`

And here is part of post data(application/json).

```
{
....
"field1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, purus erat aliquam pretium quisque mauris hymenaeos, vestibulum erat nec justo. Luctus orci non etiam at eros, duis rem dui morbi purus justo pellentesque. Vehicula velit eleifend adipiscing, odio malesuada non in ut justo diam. Conubia consequat nec. Nunc in scelerisque, libero adipiscing accumsan non tempor, nibh aliquid tortor vel. Vestibulum praesent enim id vel. Commodo eros nec est proin, mi ut ipsum, lectus varius pede a aliquet mauris, a scelerisque varius scelerisque praesent. Sapien commodo tristique, curabitur pellentesque velit praesent nonummy. Ut nec nulla consectetuer euismod, ultrices leo interdum feugiat, dapibus blandit dui consequatur arcu morbi. Sem nisl amet. Sit ante nam magna. Pulvinar adipiscing iaculis sed sit donec magna, libero urna sed, sit id facilisis integer in, ipsum justo sociosqu eu. Non eu ac donec pede, aenean imperdiet ut massa eu, nunc bibendum. Vehicula urna massa penatibus blandit interdum diam, semper cras nec purus nonummy elit. Ut augue malesuada eget a, amet rhoncus suscipit, sapien augue integer a facilisi. Sed a quisque dapibus. Lectus malesuada ante penatibus, eget volutpat etiam aliquam, integer nullam ut quam turpis. Sapien sapien ante, vestibulum ipsum risus neque mus lectus libero, ipsum nulla aptent. Eget lorem, ridiculus quis lectus placerat, dapibus eget libero. Mi in, massa eget anim malesuada eget vestibulum tellus. Non ac possimus turpis sit quam officiis, lorem donec mollis quam non maecenas iaculis, sit condimentum, ut erat orci aliquam hymenaeos id, duis proident massa non adipiscing vehicula.",
"field2": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, purus erat aliquam pretium quisque mauris hymenaeos, vestibulum erat nec justo. Luctus orci non etiam at eros, duis rem dui morbi purus justo pellentesque. Vehicula velit eleifend adipiscing, odio malesuada non in ut justo diam. Conubia consequat nec. Nunc in scelerisque, libero adipiscing accumsan non tempor, nibh aliquid tortor vel. Vestibulum praesent enim id vel. Commodo eros nec est proin, mi ut ipsum, lectus varius pede a aliquet mauris, a scelerisque varius scelerisque praesent. Sapien commodo tristique, curabitur pellentesque velit praesent nonummy. Ut nec nulla consectetuer euismod, ultrices leo interdum feugiat, dapibus blandit dui consequatur arcu morbi. Sem nisl amet. Sit ante nam magna. Pulvinar adipiscing iaculis sed sit donec magna, libero urna sed, sit id facilisis integer in, ipsum justo sociosqu eu. Non eu ac donec pede, aenean imperdiet ut massa eu, nunc bibendum. Vehicula urna massa penatibus blandit interdum diam, semper cras nec purus nonummy elit. Ut augue malesuada eget a, amet rhoncus suscipit, sapien augue integer a facilisi. Sed a quisque dapibus. Lectus malesuada ante penatibus, eget volutpat etiam aliquam, integer nullam ut quam turpis. Sapien sapien ante, vestibulum ipsum risus neque mus lectus libero, ipsum nulla aptent. Eget lorem, ridiculus quis lectus placerat, dapibus eget libero. Mi in, massa eget anim malesuada eget vestibulum tellus. Non ac possimus turpis sit quam officiis, lorem donec mollis quam non maecenas iaculis, sit condimentum, ut erat orci aliquam hymenaeos id, duis proident massa non adipiscing vehicula.",
...
}
```

As you can see the data is a bit long(hope this help to find answer).

THIS WORKS

```
{
....
"field1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, purus erat aliquam pretium quisque mauris hymenaeos, vestibulum erat nec justo. Luctus orci non etiam at eros, duis rem dui morbi purus justo pellentesque. Vehicula velit eleifend adipiscing, odio malesuada non in ut justo diam. Conubia consequat nec. Nunc in scelerisque, libero adipiscing accumsan non tempor, nibh aliquid tortor vel. Vestibulum praesent enim id vel. Commodo eros nec est proin, mi ut ipsum, lectus varius pede a aliquet mauris, a scelerisque varius scelerisque praesent. Sapien commodo tristique, curabitur pellentesque velit praesent nonummy. Ut nec nulla consectetuer euismod, ultrices leo interdum feugiat, dapibus blandit dui consequatur arcu morbi. Sem nisl amet. Sit ante nam magna. Pulvinar adipiscing iaculis sed sit donec magna, libero urna sed, sit id facilisis integer in, ipsum justo sociosqu eu. Non eu ac donec pede, aenean imperdiet ut massa eu, nunc bibendum. Vehicula urna massa penatibus blandit interdum diam, semper cras nec purus nonummy elit. Ut augue malesuada eget a, amet rhoncus suscipit, sapien augue integer a facilisi. Sed a quisque dapibus. Lectus malesuada ante penatibus, eget volutpat etiam aliquam, integer nullam ut quam turpis. Sapien sapien ante, vestibulum ipsum risus neque mus lectus libero, ipsum nulla aptent. Eget lorem, ridiculus quis lectus placerat, dapibus eget libero. Mi in, massa eget anim malesuada eget vestibulum tellus. Non ac possimus turpis sit quam officiis, lorem donec mollis quam non maecenas iaculis, sit condimentum, ut erat orci aliquam hymenaeos id, duis proident massa non adipiscing vehicula.",
"field2": "111",
...
}
```

AND THIS WORKS TOO

```
{
....
"field1": "111",
"field2": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, purus erat aliquam pretium quisque mauris hymenaeos, vestibulum erat nec justo. Luctus orci non etiam at eros, duis rem dui morbi purus justo pellentesque. Vehicula velit eleifend adipiscing, odio malesuada non in ut justo diam. Conubia consequat nec. Nunc in scelerisque, libero adipiscing accumsan non tempor, nibh aliquid tortor vel. Vestibulum praesent enim id vel. Commodo eros nec est proin, mi ut ipsum, lectus varius pede a aliquet mauris, a scelerisque varius scelerisque praesent. Sapien commodo tristique, curabitur pellentesque velit praesent nonummy. Ut nec nulla consectetuer euismod, ultrices leo interdum feugiat, dapibus blandit dui consequatur arcu morbi. Sem nisl amet. Sit ante nam magna. Pulvinar adipiscing iaculis sed sit donec magna, libero urna sed, sit id facilisis integer in, ipsum justo sociosqu eu. Non eu ac donec pede, aenean imperdiet ut massa eu, nunc bibendum. Vehicula urna massa penatibus blandit interdum diam, semper cras nec purus nonummy elit. Ut augue malesuada eget a, amet rhoncus suscipit, sapien augue integer a facilisi. Sed a quisque dapibus. Lectus malesuada ante penatibus, eget volutpat etiam aliquam, integer nullam ut quam turpis. Sapien sapien ante, vestibulum ipsum risus neque mus lectus libero, ipsum nulla aptent. Eget lorem, ridiculus quis lectus placerat, dapibus eget libero. Mi in, massa eget anim malesuada eget vestibulum tellus. Non ac possimus turpis sit quam officiis, lorem donec mollis quam non maecenas iaculis, sit condimentum, ut erat orci aliquam hymenaeos id, duis proident massa non adipiscing vehicula.",
...
}
```

BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
{
....
"field1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, purus erat aliquam pretium quisque mauris hymenaeos, vestibulum erat nec justo. Luctus orci non etiam at eros, duis rem dui morbi purus justo pellentesque. Vehicula velit eleifend adipiscing, odio malesuada non in ut justo diam. Conubia consequat nec. Nunc in scelerisque, libero adipiscing accumsan non tempor, nibh aliquid tortor vel. Vestibulum praesent enim id vel. Commodo eros nec est proin, mi ut ipsum, lectus varius pede a aliquet mauris, a scelerisque varius scelerisque praesent. Sapien commodo tristique, curabitur pellentesque velit praesent nonummy. Ut nec nulla consectetuer euismod, ultrices leo interdum feugiat, dapibus blandit dui consequatur arcu morbi. Sem nisl amet. Sit ante nam magna. Pulvinar adipiscing iaculis sed sit donec magna, libero urna sed, sit id facilisis integer in, ipsum justo sociosqu eu. Non eu ac donec pede, aenean imperdiet ut massa eu, nunc bibendum. Vehicula urna massa penatibus blandit interdum diam, semper cras nec purus nonummy elit. Ut augue malesuada eget a, amet rhoncus suscipit, sapien augue integer a facilisi. Sed a quisque dapibus. Lectus malesuada ante penatibus, eget volutpat etiam aliquam, integer nullam ut quam turpis. Sapien sapien ante, vestibulum ipsum risus neque mus lectus libero, ipsum nulla aptent. Eget lorem, ridiculus quis lectus placerat, dapibus eget libero. Mi in, massa eget anim malesuada eget vestibulum tellus. Non ac possimus turpis sit quam officiis, lorem donec mollis quam non maecenas iaculis, sit condimentum, ut erat orci aliquam hymenaeos id, duis proident massa non adipiscing vehicula.",
"field2": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, purus erat aliquam pretium quisque mauris hymenaeos, vestibulum erat nec justo. Luctus orci non etiam at eros, duis rem dui morbi purus justo pellentesque. Vehicula velit eleifend adipiscing, odio malesuada non in ut justo diam. Conubia consequat nec. Nunc in scelerisque, libero adipiscing accumsan non tempor, nibh aliquid tortor vel. Vestibulum praesent enim id vel. Commodo eros nec est proin, mi ut ipsum, lectus varius pede a aliquet mauris, a scelerisque varius scelerisque praesent. Sapien commodo tristique, curabitur pellentesque velit praesent nonummy. Ut nec nulla consectetuer euismod, ultrices leo interdum feugiat, dapibus blandit dui consequatur arcu morbi. Sem nisl amet. Sit ante nam magna. Pulvinar adipiscing iaculis sed sit donec magna, libero urna sed, sit id facilisis integer in, ipsum justo sociosqu eu. Non eu ac donec pede, aenean imperdiet ut massa eu, nunc bibendum. Vehicula urna massa penatibus blandit interdum diam, semper cras nec purus nonummy elit. Ut augue malesuada eget a, amet rhoncus suscipit, sapien augue integer a facilisi. Sed a quisque dapibus. Lectus malesuada ante penatibus, eget volutpat etiam aliquam, integer nullam ut quam turpis. Sapien sapien ante, vestibulum ipsum risus neque mus lectus libero, ipsum nulla aptent. Eget lorem, ridiculus quis lectus placerat, dapibus eget libero. Mi in, massa eget anim malesuada eget vestibulum tellus. Non ac possimus turpis sit quam officiis, lorem donec mollis quam non maecenas iaculis, sit condimentum, ut erat orci aliquam hymenaeos id, duis proident massa non adipiscing vehicula.",
...
}
```

I think this might be a problem of rest api post data size limit.
But the total size isn't more than 15KB.

FYI : It returns 500 (internal server error). I checked server side php log but nothing found. Also checked with WP Rest API log plugin but it doesn't log this api call.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: check server site php post limit...whats about your wp_memory_limit?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it's because server side php configuration. Increased buffer size and it worked.